Consistency Issues When Multiple Servers Access a File
I have multiple servers that cannot communicate with each other. They can only read and write files on a certain website using a remote API, which only includes read and write functions. I also cannot design a server to manage locks. How can I design a mechanism to ensure the consistency of their operations on a certain file?
I have designed a mechanism that uses a file as a lock. Each time it attempts to acquire the lock, it waits for a while and then checks if the lock was successfully acquired. I am not sure if such a mechanism is reasonable. Here is the pseudocode:
tryLock, lockFileName = False, ""

while True:
    if not tryLock and length(getLockFiles()) <= 0:
        tryLock = True
        lockFileName = uuid()
        uploadFile(lockFileName)
    else:
        if length(getLockFiles()) <= 1:
            break

        for oldLockFileName in getLockFiles():
            if oldLockFileName < lockFileName:
                tryLock = False
                delFile(lockFileName)
                break

        if tryLock:
            break

    sleep(10 milliseconds)

do_some_thing()

delFile(lockFileName)

The problem with this approach is that the waiting time must be longer than the time it takes to upload any file for the lock mechanism to work correctly. However, the time it takes to upload a file is uncertain unless a very large value is set for the waiting time. I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve this problem.
I also have another plan that can ensure success, but doing so will result in very low efficiency.
files = getAllFilesWithPrefix("data_")
data = mergeAndResolveConflicts(files)
data = doSomething(data)
file = newFile(name = "data_" + newHashId(), data = data)
uploadFile(file)

